# Why the ONLINEUSERID is empty when I use accoreconsole.exe

Tags: c#, autocad-plugin

I'm writing an app that is run on accoreconsole.exe, when I try to get the system variable ONLINEUSERID, it always returns empty but it returns the user id within AutoCAD. I'm sure I'm logged into the Autodesk Account. I need this USER Id to use it in the entitlements code.